# Possible to upgrade from EE1 to EE2 Core?

Tags: ee1, migration

Is it possible to upgrade a normal version of EE1 to EE2 core ? Is there a guide?
Thanks

Comment: What modules in EE1 are being used?

Comment: wygwam and ngen file field

Comment: Sorry, shoulda been clearer: Ellis Lab EE modules. Does your EE 1 install use any of the EE native modules that aren't a part of EE core, i.e., Mailing List, Email, Member, Query modules, etc.

Comment: ok, installed on ee1: mailing list, member, pages, query, referer, rss, search, simple tag, statistics, trackback, weblog

Comment: This EE1 -> EE2 Core may not be an option for you unless you're willing to scale way, way, way back down. See "what's included" here: https://store.ellislab.com/

Comment: for email i use freeform, so i don't need it. For "member", if i already have registered user, is it a problem? I don't need the others modules